# unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred...Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type

Tags: c#, linq

could anyone help me please? Following my code and "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in GelatoProject.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'GelatoProject.RecipeVariables'." is the message.

```
// ...
using (var db = new GelatoProjectDBEntities())
{
    RecipeVariables selected = 
        (RecipeVariables)comboBoxRecipeDetail.SelectedItem;

    var results = (from x in db.Recipe_Parameters
                select new RecipeVariables 
                        { 
                            Id = x.Id, 
                            RecipeDetail = x.recipeDetail, 
                            Parameter = x.parameter, 
                            RangeDetail = x.rangeDetail, 
                            RangeValue = x.value.ToString() 
                        }
               )
                .Where(x => x.RecipeDetail == selected.RecipeDetail && x.Parameter == "totalsolids" && x.RangeDetail == "Max")
                .FirstOrDefault();

    totsolidsRangeMax = decimal.Parse(results.RangeValue);

    MessageBox.Show(totsolidsRangeMax.ToString());
}
// ...

class RecipeVariables
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameIngredient { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string LBName { get { return NameIngredient + " - " + Brand;}}
    public string RecipeDetail { get; set; }
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
    public string RangeDetail { get; set; }
    public string RangeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RecipeVariables selected = (RecipeVariables)comboBoxRecipeDetail.SelectedItem;
```

`comboBoxRecipeDetail.SelectedItem` is a string - text that you see when you clicked on the combobox. It can not be cast to `RecipeVariables`

Change your code to:

```
using (var db = new GelatoProjectDBEntities())
{
    RecipeVariables selected = new RecipeVariables()
                               {
                                   RecipeDetail = (string)comboBoxRecipeDetail.SelectedItem
                               };

    // var results = ...
}
```

This will create a new RecipeVariables object and then set its RecipeDetail property to the text for selected combobox item.

Comment: Thank you Tadija for your reply! I will edit main code with RecipeVariables code.

Comment: I edited the code. Also `RangeValue = x.value.ToString()` might be your next problem

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: now I'm in x.value.ToString() problem...
Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: That is an unrelated problem, please open another question so I can answer that too. Btw, did this solve your current question?

Comment: your answer about x.value.tostring() should solve my first question, I'm trying to open another post but I can't before 90 minutes...

Comment: @Mirko you need to click the tick sign under the vote icon to accept this answer if it solved your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Selman thank you for the suggestions, I didn't know it because I'm new...